curl failing in Google Cloud Build when using a secret
As part of my CD deploy pipe in Google Cloud Build I would like to notify a Slack channel, but I am struggling to use the Secret Manager to supply the secret notification endpoint. This build config is failing on the "Notify" stage with:

curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname

This is my simplified build config:
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    id: Test #  this works as expected
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        echo $$SLACK_ENDPOINT
    secretEnv: ['SLACK_ENDPOINT']

  - name: curlimages/curl
    id: Notify
    args:
      - -d
      - '{ "text": "channel test" }'
      - -H
      - Content-type:application/json
      - -X
      - POST
      - $$SLACK_ENDPOINT #  if I replace this with the secret value, it works
    secretEnv: ['SLACK_ENDPOINT']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - env: 'SLACK_ENDPOINT'
      versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SLACK_ENDPOINT/versions/2

The secret is a normal looking url which works fine if I use it straight in the config:
https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0redactedK5/B0redactedJX/67redactedMK

I have also tried wrapping the secret with single quotes and got the same error message:
   - POST
   - '$$SLACK_ENDPOINT'


I believe the entrypoint might be the problem here. I think the variable doesn't get expanded when using curl directly. From the docs: "Add an entrypoint field pointing to bash to use the bash tool in the build step. This is required to refer to the environment variable for the secret." > https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#access-utf8-secrets

We just got an issue with curl not working in our build as well. We are using a secret, though I have not tested without it yet. We're using curl from bash in the gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud builder though.

@ptf curl was removed from cloud-builders/gcloud recently

@JannieTheunissen Ah that explains it, thanks!

Thanks @p13rr0m for pointing out that resolving secrets needs an entrypoint context.
The officially recommended curlimages/curl does not support a bash entrypoint, but Cloud Builders have a dedicated image for curl that can take an entrypoint. I got this working:
  # Notify
  - name: 'gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/ubuntu_20_0_4'
    id: Notify
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - 'curl -d "{ \"text\": \"✅ CMS deployed to $_SERVICE_NAME\" }" -H "Content-type:application/json" -X POST $$SLACK_ENDPOINT'
    secretEnv: ['SLACK_ENDPOINT']

